# Infinite-inline function call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, currying

I am trying to chain a function to itself so I can call it this way (infinitely):

```
infiny()('a')('b')('c')('d');
```

I have this code so far, but it's only catching the first function call after the `infiny()`:

```
function infiny() {
    return function( output ) {
        alert(output);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I want it to output me four alerts here, for all four arguments: `a, b, c and d`

**Is this possible?** - My current example shows no overflow, syntax error, failures, except it does not invoke function calls after `('a')`.

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation to learn how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). And FYI, you should get an error. I get `TypeError: object is not a function`.

Answer (score 3):

You may return a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) which returns a reference to itself:

```
function infiny() {
    return function ret( output ) {
        alert(output);
        return ret;
    }
}
infiny()('a')('b')('c')('d');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uMWU/)

---

`this` references the `window` object in your examples. That's because simply calling a function with  `()` without method syntax does not set the `this` reference, and in this case, in non-strict mode, the `this` reference is to set to the `window` object.

The `thisArg` resolving is described on [#11.2.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.3) and the `null`/`undefined` -> `window` translation on [#10.4.3](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3). The spec wording is not very friendly, so here's an article that explains all the possible ways that the `this` reference may be set when entering a function execution context: [Understanding JavaScript's this keyword](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/)

Comment: Both answers are correct, and you both have alot of reputation... which one should I accept!? :D

Comment: Accept the one that helped you the most. If you like both answers equally accept the first one posted (i.e., Fabrício's answer).

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
function infiny() {
    return function test( output ) {
        alert(output);
        return test;
    }
}
```

That is, have the inner function return a reference to itself by giving it a name (I've used `test`, but you can use something more meaningful).

Returning `this` doesn't work because `this` isn't the function - even if you called the function with `new` you would find that `this` is not the function itself. For more information about using `this` have a look at [what MDN has to say about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner function at all:

```
function infiny(x) {
    console.log(x)
    return infiny;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want it that way!

Comment: @ZlatanO.: Answers on StackOverflow are meant to be useful to the whole community, not (only) to the original asker, so I'll keep it here if you don't mind.